# C# how to parse XML into Json with Json.net

Tags: c#, .net, json, xml

i have an XML file and i want to parse it to Json and print it on the screen. how do i use Json.net to parse it from XML into Json. thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Using by JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode...
See this Link http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertXmlToJson.htm

Comment: do you have any idea why i cant use "XmlDoucument". there is library that i need to download?

Comment: you must add newtonsoft.json package,you can use nuget for add package...This link Convert XML to JSON with XmlDocument